# Animated ScrollView

Tags: java, android

I have this code which runs when an Async HTTP call is made on a `HorizontalScrollView`

```
            //These 3 defined outside of the method
            ObjectAnimator animatorR = null;
            ObjectAnimator animatorL = null;
            boolean loop = true;

            Inside the method
            if (animatorL != null) animatorL.cancel();
            animatorL = null;
            if (animatorR != null) animatorR.cancel();
            animatorR = null;
            HorizontalScrollView sv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
            loop = true;
            sv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    animatorL.cancel();
                    animatorR.cancel();
                    loop = false;
                    sv.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            animatorR = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(sv, "scrollX", sv.getMaxScrollAmount()).setDuration(4000);
            animatorL = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(sv, "scrollX", 0).setDuration(4000);

            animatorR.removeAllListeners();
            animatorR.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    Log.d("AnimR", "Ended");
                    if (loop && animatorL != null) animatorL.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
            animatorR.start();

            animatorL.removeAllListeners();
            animatorL.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    Log.d("AnimL", "Ended");
                    if (loop && animatorR != null) animatorR.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
        }
```

This is my first time using Animators and the code seems very clunky. Where could I make improvements to this code?

Comment: Hi, welcome to CodeReview.SE. Can you please provide the whole class or whatever this snippet was supposed to be in ?

Comment: will you please look at the code and make sure that your indentation is correct?  it looks like you have an `if` statement that is out of alignment

Comment: @Josay the code this from is about 1000 lines long, I just cut out the part I wanted looking at at the moment, should I post all of it? @ Malachi yeah ones out of line when I copied it here, it's inline in the actual file.

Comment: You don't need to post the whole file. I see a couple of potential improvements. I will write up an answer either later today or tomorrow!

Answer (score 3):

The biggest change I can see here would be to extract a class out of the two anonymous inner classes. The two variations are exactly the same except for which `ObjectAnimator` they should call next, and which logging tag to use. So let's extract a class and pass those values to its constructor: (Place the code below inside the same class as you are using right now)

```
private class MyAnimListener implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
    private ObjectAnimator  other;
    private final String    logMessage;

    public MyAnimListener(String logMessage, ObjectAnimator startOther) {
        this.logMessage = logMessage;
        this.other = startOther;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        Log.d(logMessage, "Ended");
        if (loop && other != null) 
            other.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
    }
}
```

You could then use this code to add the listeners:

```
animatorR.addListener(new MyAnimListener("AnimR", animatorL));
animatorL.addListener(new MyAnimListener("AnimL", animatorR));
```

However, if your two `animator` instances often switch to/from null, I would think about what it actually is that you are trying to achieve. (Honestly I'm not sure what you are trying to do, which can make this a bit of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

If you really really want the two animator instances to switch to/from null, then you will have to use two variables for the `MyAnimListener` and modify its `ObjectAnimator other` field, something like this:

```
    // Variable declarations
animRListener = new MyAnimListener("AnimR", animatorL);
animatorR.addListener(animRListener);
animLListener = new MyAnimListener("AnimL", animatorR);
animatorL.addListener(animLListener);

// Later on
animatorR = null;
animLListener.other = null;
```

Besides this, I actually think your code might be cleaner than it looks, if that makes any sense...

---

I would recommend using the same `tag` parameter for all `Log` calls throughout your entire map. The Logcat utility can filter on a specific tag, by using it like this:

```
adb -d logcat YourTag:D YourOtherTag:D System.err:W *:S
```

I usually use something like this to be informed about both my own tags, stack traces from applications gone mad, and some other more or less useful Android messages:

```
adb -d logcat MyTag:D MyOtherTag:D MyThirdTag:D dalvikvm:I AndroidRuntime:E ResourceType:W PackageManager:I System.err:W *:S
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). The reason they're going to null at the moment is because I had a problem with looping, when that block of code ran for the second time (And third etc...) the animation would happen twice, I tried using `.cancel()` but it didn't seem to fix it, but setting it to null did.